# Why does the speed of light totally prevent instantaneous information exchange?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light, causality, information

Based on the classical light-cone approach it's easy to see you can't transmit information faster than $c$ but why does the speed of light (as far as I know) treat information transmission in this way formally?

For instance going the Sci-Fi route, in Orson Scott Card's Ender universe there is a device called an ansible which seems to be described as some sort of coupled state device - pair two devices and as they move apart they remain linked. The details probably don't matter since this is a hypothetical question.
With ansibles, you obviously can only move the devices subject to normal physics so if you found a colony 100 light-years away, it takes (at least) 100 years to get the ansible there. But then, you have communication.

Is it possible in reasonably simple (say degree but not post-graduate level) terms to explain why this is fundamentally impossible, why information cannot by any means violate the light-speed limit, rather than that we just can't think of a way to do it?

Comment: what would you use to transmit information? probably the fastest "messenger" you have

Comment: That's saying information can't travel FTL merely as a corollary that you can't find anything to physically send FTL. My understanding is that information is considered a "first class citizen" as it were, making the whole discussion of FTL information travel moot.

Comment: Interesting related article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone

Comment: @Phoenix87 the fictional device he's talking about transmits information faster than light by using some sort of entangled particles that could be manipulated without breaking the entanglement; such that one particle could be "wiggled" and the other would instantly do the same, allowing a faster-than-light telegraph machine of sorts. It doesn't rely on photons.

Comment: Possible dupliates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119299/question-regarding-ftl-information-transfer-between-two-inertial-frames http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114370/time-travel-outside-of-light-cone-without-causality-violation/114467#114467

Comment: FWIW the ansible (that name anyway) was invented by Ursula Le Guin. The name was taken up by others including OSC.

Comment: @SteveJessop is right - SciFi Citations (for the OED) has ["ansible" earliest cite 1966 U. K. Le Guin Rocannon's World 113](http://www.jessesword.com/sf/view/16) "Noting the coordinates at which the ansible sender was set, he changed them to the coordinates of the League HILF Survey Base for Galactic Area 8, at Kerguelen, on the planet New South Georgia—the only coordinates he knew without reference to a handbook."

Comment: Faster than light communications isn't really impossible.  It's just that when it occurs the Time Lords arrive and use a flashy thing to make you forget it happened.

Comment: @HotLicks Is that where the men in black got their flashy thing from?

Comment: @Jim - I forget.

Answer (score 36):

The thing about the speed of light $c$ is that it's not just a number associated with a certain type of particle. While we could talk about the *mass* of the *proton*, and there would be no problem assuming non-protons had greater or lesser masses, the value $c$ is an entirely different beast.

$c$ is an intrinsic property of spacetime itself, not of the particles in spacetime. You wouldn't expect there to exist anything (particle, signal, information) that you could insert into spacetime with the property "changes the nature of spacetime for itself."

The above is meant to undermine the "if it's just a property of everything we've found so far, we haven't ruled out finding things without this property" line of thought.

---

For a more concrete demonstration of what goes wrong when you alter the structure of spacetime as we know it, take a look at the ["tachyonic antitelephone"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone). This demonstrates how any abstract communication faster than light leads to causality violations as observed by even not-faster-than-light observers.

There are many variations on the thought experiment; here's one of them (with the math worked out in the linked article): $A$ is moving away from $B$ with speed $v < c$ in $B$'s reference frame. $A$ sends a faster-than-light message to $B$, who responds in kind with a reply. The problem is for sufficiently fast (but not faster than $c$!) speeds $v$, $A$ will receive the reply *before* sending the message. Faster-than-light anything begets time travel.

---

Since it gets repeated far, far too often, I'll also counter quantum entanglement arguments here. Quantum entanglement does *nothing* in the hypothetical "why can't this communicate faster than light?" scenarios other than guarantee that the two particles will "collapse" to the same (or opposite, or orthogonal, or whatever) states when either is observed. The only quantum mechanical aspect of the whole thing is the fact that the eventual collapsed state can't even exist before the measurement (it's not a hidden variable).

But the *correlation* -- the thing you want to rely on to communicate faster than light -- could be achieved entirely classically. Take a red marble and a blue marble, put them in a bag, and draw one out randomly without looking. Lock your marble in a box, and hand the bag to someone else, who also doesn't peak. Send the person far away. Then, look at your marble. If it's blue, you *instantly know* the other person has red. But you transmitted nothing. All quantum mechanics does is make it so who has which marble isn't pre-determined.

This shouldn't come as a surprise, because the only notions of space and time in quantum mechanics *are the ones from spacetime itself*. Quantum mechanics doesn't come equipped with some independent notion of distances. So whatever structure spacetime has applies to quantum things just as much as marbles and people and signals.

---

Everything said here stays true even in general relativity, by the way. Enabling things to move faster than $c$ still leads to causality violations. Even wrapping things in a "warp bubble" and moving *that* faster than $c$ leads to causality violations.

Comment: That sounds very compelling. However, maybe it could turn out that the star was not really 100 light-years away because of a [wormhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole). So choosing another route from here to the star could be a shortcut so that the true distance is only e.g. 10 light-years. However, my comment may be off-topic since using a wormhole is not "faster-than-light".

Comment: Ah, but what if you've lost your marbles?

Comment: +1, good answer. I only want to add a N.B. that all this causality violation stuff is based on the notion that there is no privileged or universally preferred frame of reference, which we reasonably believe is true. If there were such a frame of reference, causality violation would easily be avoided by restricting  the measurement of FTL speeds to only be valid in that preferred frame.

Comment: Just as quantum entanglement is misunderstood to suggest faster-than-light communication (which you addressed), so is the [Bertlmann's Socks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinhold_Bertlmann#Bertlmann.E2.80.99s_Socks) concept of correlations to explain the non-classical phenomena of quantum entanglement. It is fundamentally more subtle than your blue/red marble analogy, and to leave it at that is to propagate the misunderstanding I'm afraid.

Comment: As a lay person, I find this description of entanglement exciting. It is exciting as it presents the system as knowledge inference, not transfer. I didn't anticipate that and I love it.

Comment: @JiK "But the correlation ... could be achieved entirely classically." This is false, whether or not it is connected to the prior sentence. Quantum mechanically entangled states achieve correlations which simply _cannot_ be achieved classically. One of my favorite presentations of this is in [Lev Vaidman's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9808022) in which the Greenberger–Horne–Zeilinger state is explored with a game.

Comment: @JiK Unfortunately that's not enough (read the whole paragraph - he's talking about quantum mechanics specifically). This is a common mischaracterization of quantum entanglement that John Bell had discussed in his 1980 paper [Bertlmann's Socks and the Nature of Reality](https://cds.cern.ch/record/142461/files/198009299.pdf).

Comment: The essential problem with the blue/red marble description of quantum entanglement is that it doesn't incorporate a _choice_ of measurement by each person. This would be like restricting the direction of spin or polarization on each end of an EPR experiment to only a single direction. In that case, the author would be correct in that the observed correlations could be achieved classically. However once one allows for a _choice_ of how to measure their particle, then the observed correlations cannot be achieved classically. This is the essential mischaracterization.

Comment: Is it correct to state that "c" has little or nothing to do with the speed of "light" - it is the ultimate speed of spacetime itself - or of information therewithin. Light is moving at "infinite" (or the maximum) speed within an "finite" media. Matter (i.e. photons) *can* move at "c" - matter just cannot be "accelerated" to "c". (Photons are "created" moving at "c", and therefore are not "accelerated to it").

Answer (score 7):

Faster than light communication would violate [causality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_(physics)) If FTL communication was somehow allowed by nature, then you could kill someone before firing the gun which just doesn't make any sense. You simply cannot have something that is caused by some event happen *before* the event occurs. Put simply, FTL communication gives rise to paradoxes.

Comment: [As for _why_ it violates causality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52249/how-does-faster-than-light-travel-violate-causality).

Comment: "*You simply cannot have something that is caused by some event happen before the event occurs*" - you don't know that! Violating causality does not make something impossible. The very notion of "impossibility" flies in the face of the philosophy of scientific inquiry. Just a thought.

Comment: I don't think the gun analogy is helpful here. How would sending pure information FTL let me kill someone before I fire a gun?

Comment: @quant Understandable and justified. But! The whole of modern physics is build on these principles for a reason. As soon as you consider FTL communication, paradoxes arise between reference frames and we cannot have that. Would you consider energy violation in one frame possible where in a different frame energy is conserved? Can the laws of physics contradict each other between reference frames? Check out the link above by Cole btw it gives a nice example of how causality is violated.

Comment: @Mr.Boy the link above has a nice description of a similar example.

Comment: @PhotonicBoom I like to view contradictions as merely breaking our understanding of the universe. If the world is flat then going straight ahead and ending up where you started reduces to a paradox, just as if the first law of thermodynamics holds then perpetual motion is impossible. All notions of law and truth lie on a bedrock of prepositions. I think yours is a good answer, I'm merely playing devil's advocate! Can the laws of physics contradict each other? No, by definition. But reality is not at the whim of _our_ physical laws, and when they are found to contradict they must be changed.

Comment: @quant There is a simple reason that violations of causality are seen as impossible: Assume you can send a message back in time. You can build a machine that waits 10 seconds for a message, then waits 5 seconds, then sends a message to itself 10 seconds in the past. It sends message A if it receives message B and sends message B if it receives message A from itself or receives no message at all. Turn the machine on, and you have a paradox. The only possible outcome is that every such machine just coincidentally malfunctions, under all possible external circumstances, just to avoid the paradox.

Comment: @Cory I'm having problems connecting the scenario to "the only possible outcome." "The paradox" you are seeming to suggest is that it can only receive either Message A or B. What if both or neither was returned? You would know time travel is possible if you receive both but if you receive neither you don't know if the messages are sent to another space-time or if the machine just doesn't work. (*Multi-verse theory?*)

Comment: @DoubleDouble I should be more clear: At most one message is allowed to be sent. If a message is received, then a different message is always sent. If no message is sent, then a message is sent. Assuming the device works properly, you have a paradox.

Comment: @DoubleDouble As for the multiple-worlds idea, this is not communication back in time in a meaningful sense. It's merely communication with a different physical system which happens to have some similarities to prior states of this system.

Comment: @DoubleDouble The paradox example is simpler if you instead imagine a machine which sends a message into the past if and only if it received no message from the future. Then there is only one possible message, and sending it means it will not be sent, whereas not sending it means that it will be sent. As long as this simple machine operates as designed, there is no possible outcome. Either such a machine must always fail to operate as designed, or a machine cannot be designed to send messages to itself in the past. It's just a boiled-down grandfather paradox.

Answer (score 5):

One principal that would be violated is causality.  Just looking at things from a single frame (such as here on earth), there is no apparent problem.  But as soon as you examine things in other frames it gets tricky.

Once you allow for travel faster than $c$ in one frame, it becomes possible to construct a series of messages, each of which travels forward in time in some particular frame, but where the final message arrives at the transmitter before the time when it sends the message.

Here's a site with some good Minkowski diagrams for it.
http://www.theculture.org/rich/sharpblue/archives/000089.html

Answer (score 1):

Information has to be transmitted *by* something.  The laws of Physics state that the maximum speed that anything can move at is the speed of light, which seems to be a fundamental property of the universe.  So, if we can find something that can travel faster than light then it would be possible to transmit information faster, but until then we are limited to light speed. [edited to remove dubious suggestion that quantum entanglement might enable faster-than-light information transmission].

Comment: So if such a hypothetical mechanism existed, this wouldn't violate any laws? I guess that's what I'm asking really - does FTL information transmission violate special relativity or is it just a side-effect of SR that we cannot find a way to _do_ the transmission?

Comment: In the context of special relativity, as I understand it, FTL travel of _anything_ would violate it.  I don't think information would be treated any differently.  Therefore, information travelling FTL would violate special relativity. I guess the question is, in the future, can we find something outside the scope of special relativity that would enable FTL information transmission (e.g. quantum effects)?

Comment: @Mr.Boy yes such a mechanism would violate causality.  If you can transmit information faster than light in one reference frame, then you can find some other frame where the messages arrives before the transmitter sends.  This can't happen when $c$ is the fastest speed for information transfer.

Comment: @ Chris White: Ok, thanks for setting me straight on that. I'll edit my answer to remove the nefarious suggestion.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I think that might be the root of the answer I'm looking for. Would you consider writing that up as a full answer?

Comment: @Time4Tea There are not indications that quantum entanglement can convey information, in fact it's been proven that it can't.

Comment: @SeñorO on that point, if you change the state of members of an entangled system, would it not be true that the state would be instantly changed in the appropriate entangled pair member? If you were so inclined, setting up a dot matrix of entangled states, which you subsequently cause to collapse in a pattern would result in effective information transfer via the medium of instantaneous state collapse by virtue of how it is set up, thinking in basic terms?

Comment: @MyStream: I think what they're saying is that you can't _choose_ what state each particle collapses to like that (i.e. to create a pattern), so even though the _effect_ of each collapse is intantaneous, no information is being transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to understand is the consideration of the two components of c, [permittivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity) and [permeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability) of vacuum. They are two constants of space, and already by their name we understand that it is a physical property/ a physical limit of space not to transmit any radiation faster than with light speed.

The hypothetical proper time of photons is zero, because from their hypothetical point of view they are not taking part in spacetime, their Minkowski diagram would be reduced to a dimensionless point. In this sense it could be said that information is transmitted immediately - but this is a consideration which does not take into account the spacetime where we are living in as observers. In the same way as there is a fundamental law (the second SR postulate) that light speed cannot be observed faster than c, there is no mean for spacetime observers to get information faster than at light speed.